# MySQL statement need - Select recent message from each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm working on MySQL and here's my data :

Tables :

User :

```
+----+----------+
+ id + username +
+----+----------+
```

Messages :

```
+----+------+----+---------+---------------+
+ id + from + to + message + date_creation +
+----+------+----+---------+---------------+
```

Need : 
I want to retrieve (one) the last message sent by every user to user id '20' (for instance)

I tried :

```
SELECT u.username
     , m.id, u.lastActivity
     , LEFT( m.message, 60 ) AS message
     , m.lu
     , m.date_envoi 
  FROM messages m
     , user u 
 WHERE m.to_id = 1 
   AND u.id = m.from_id 
 GROUP 
    BY u.username 
 ORDER 
    BY m.date_envoi DESC
```

Comment: Please post the SQL that you have attempted for solving this problem.

Comment: I tryed : SELECT u.username, m.id, u.lastActivity, LEFT( m.message, 60 ) AS message, m.lu, m.date_envoi
FROM messages AS m, user u
WHERE m.to_id =1
AND u.id = m.from_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY m.date_envoi DESC
**This gives me a good result but not the LAST message**

Comment: Do not use comma join syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.

```
select m1.* 
from
`Messages` m1
join 
(
    select m.`from`, max(m.date_creation) as date_creation 
    from
    `Messages` m
    where m.to = 20
    group by m.`from`   
) t on m1.`from` = t.`from` and m1.date_creation = t.date_creation
```

Comment: Is there any other possible way to write it differently ? Because I'm working on Symfony2, and obviously, DQL doesnt support the "...FROM xx JOIN ( SELECT..." Thanks

Comment: @YoussefElGharbaoui Create a VIEW and select from that. (Although why it's "obvious" beats me!

Comment: According to few try + searching on google + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211894/symfony2-doctrine-from-sql-to-dql/21212289?noredirect=1#21212289 This cant be / Hard to perform, although, creating Views on Symfony, not a piece of cake, is there another altenative that I can use to perform the same result ? Thank you